# Connecting Jenkins to Docker on Windows 10 - connection refused

Tags: docker, jenkins

Running jenkins on latest image in container in windows 10. Also have docker for desktop.  In docker GUi, i checked the open port 2375 for tcp connections  checkbox.
Still, when trying to add docker as cloud in jenkins  at  *tcp://localhost:2375*  i get connection refused.

What is wrong ?